# python-vlc will not embed gtk widget into window, but open a new window instead

Tags: python, gtk3, libvlc, python-vlc

I'm working on a `gtk3` front end for `libvlc` written in python using `python-vlc`. I'm following the `gtk3` example from the [python-vlc github page](https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc/blob/master/examples/gtkvlc.py), but am experiencing strange behavior. I have a widget that looks like that:

```py
import gi
import sys
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class PlayerWidget(Gtk.DrawingArea):

    __gtype_name__ = 'VLCWidget'

    def __init__(self, instance):

        Gtk.DrawingArea.__init__(self)
        self.player = instance.media_player_new()

        def handle_embed(*args):
            if sys.platform == 'win32':
                self.player.set_hwnd(self.get_window().get_handle())
            else:
                self.player.set_xwindow(self.get_window().get_xid())
            return True
        self.connect("realize", handle_embed)
        self.set_size_request(320, 200)
```

I embed it here:

```py
import vlc
import sys
from widgets.player import PlayerWidget
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk


class VideoPlayer(Gtk.Window):
    CONST_APP_NAME = "video player"

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        if 'linux' in sys.platform:
            self.instance = vlc.Instance("--no-xlib")
        else:
            self.instance = vlc.Instance()

        self.set_default_size(800, 600)
        header = Gtk.HeaderBar(title=self.CONST_APP_NAME)
        header.set_subtitle("Filename.mp4")
        header.set_show_close_button(True) # this one is the troublemaker
        self.set_titlebar(header)
        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

        self.player_widget = PlayerWidget(self.instance)
        self.add(self.player_widget)

    def show_window(self):
        self.show_all()
        Gtk.main()

    def set_media(self, fname):
        self.player_widget.player.set_media(self.instance.media_new(fname))

    def play(self):
        self.player_widget.play()


if not len(sys.argv) > 0:
    print('Please provide a filename')
    sys.exit(1)

p = VideoPlayer()
p.set_media(sys.argv[1])
p.play()
p.show_window()
p.instance.release()
```

It works fine if I embed it into an empty Gtk.window. If, however, I add a `HeaderBar` to that window as well and then add a close button to that `HeaderBar` using `set_show_close_button(True)` it stops working as expected. The `PlayerWidget` will not be shown embedded anymore, but instead a new (second) window will be opened where the video is played. If I do not add the close button to the `HeaderBar` the widget gets embedded just fine.

A warning is thrown to the console: `xcb_window window error: X server failure`

I first thought it could be because I use gnome under wayland, but it occurs on `X` as well as on `wayland`.

Any help is appreciated.

*Update 1: Added full code example. When I ran it today, the first time it actually worked as expected, but after that the same bug as described above occured again. Very weird.*

Comment: Couldn't reproduce your issue. Try the following: Do [`self.set_decorated(False)`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Window.html#Gtk.Window.set_decorated). Change `p.play()` to `GLib.idle_add(p.play)` to show the `PlayerWidget` before start playing.

Comment: Calling Play _before_ show window seems weird to me. LibVLC will create a window itself if the one you provided is invalid or not initialized. Play should only be called when you're sure everything has been initialized properly.

Comment: Running p.play before creating the window was the problem. Works like a charm now, thanks you both lot! Should I create an answer to my own question now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mtz and @stovfl correctly pointed out, the problem was that I started the video playback (`p.play()`) before creating the window (`p.show_window()`).

As suggested I used `GLib.idle_add(p.play)` to let the window start the playback once it's ready. The GLib module can be imported using `from gi.repository import GLib`.